# Need Referral Name for downloading Pega Personal edition for self-learning

Tags: pega

I am new to pega, i want to download and install pega 7 for personal learning. I am going through the process of downloading but at the end it asks for "Please enter the name of the pega sales representative or partner who referred you to this page" , i am giving a name  lets say " Bonny Kumar" and hitting submit. Its showing me "Your software request has been failed.I am giving the screen here . Please help me .. Thanks is advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I created Service Request from Support Portal (https://pdn.pega.com/support/my-support-portal). Support helped me.

Who is " Bonny Kumar" ? Is it sales manage from Pega Systems? U can't download Pega Personal Edition, if u are not partner.